# SQL SELECT Query not working while working with PDO AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo, mysqli

I have a SQL query which is working perfectly while executing it web hosting PhpMyadmin.
But when I am using it via php code its not returning any any data.
Waiting for any kind help.

SQL Query :

```
SELECT
`students`.`name`
, `students`.`fatherName`
, `students`.`motherName`
, `students`.`regNo`
, `course`.`courseName`
, `subject`.`subjectName`
, `subject`.`subjectID`
, `course`.`examRollNo`
, `year`.`yearName`
, `papers`.`paperCode`
FROM
`jnuskenresult`.`course`
INNER JOIN `result`.`students` 
    ON (`course`.`ID` = `students`.`ID`)
INNER JOIN `result`.`subject` 
    ON (`subject`.`courseID` = `course`.`courseID`)
INNER JOIN `result`.`year` 
    ON (`year`.`subjectID` = `subject`.`subjectID`)
INNER JOIN `result`.`papers` 
    ON (`papers`.`yearID` = `year`.`yearID`)
WHERE (`students`.`regNo` ='ABC-AA-12345'
AND `year`.`yearName` ='Third Year');
```

This is working perfectly 
But the below php PDP code not working on the same database.

```
    $data =urldecode(($_GET['appno']));
    //$dataSubject =htmlspecialchars(trim($_GET['subject']));
    $dataYear =htmlspecialchars($_GET['year']);


$sql="SELECT
    `students`.`name`
    , `students`.`fatherName`
    , `students`.`motherName`
    , `students`.`regNo`
    , `course`.`courseName`
    , `subject`.`subjectName`
    , `subject`.`subjectID`
    , `course`.`examRollNo`
    , `year`.`yearName`
    , `papers`.`paperCode`
    FROM
    `SOMEDBNAME`.`course`
    INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`students` 
    ON (`course`.`ID` = `students`.`ID`)
    INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`subject` 
    ON (`subject`.`courseID` = `course`.`courseID`)
    INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`year` 
    ON (`year`.`subjectID` = `subject`.`subjectID`)
    INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`papers` 
    ON (`papers`.`yearID` = `year`.`yearID`)
    WHERE (`students`.`regNo` =?
    AND `year`.`yearName` =?)";

    // we have to tell the PDO that we are going to send values to the query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    // Now we execute the query passing an array to execute();
    $results = $stmt->execute(array($data,$dataYear));
    //$results = $stmt->execute(array($data));
    // Extract the values from $result
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
    //echo $error[2];
```

The other same codes are working while I am sending one parameter.
I am sending two parameter via ajax call as GET method.
Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick reply. It showing" Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::query()"

Comment: show dump of `$data` and `$datayear` please

Comment: Is it still giving fatal error?

Comment: are you sure you show the full code fragment? there is no `query()` call in this fragment, but fatal error saying there IS `query()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I finally got a working solution for this issue.

```
if (isset($_GET['appno'])) { 

$data =$_GET['appno']; 
$data = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $data); 

$dataYear =$_GET['year']; 

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT
`students`.`name`
, `students`.`fatherName`
, `students`.`motherName`
, `course`.`courseName`
, `subject`.`subjectName`
, `year`.`yearName`
, `students`.`applicationNo`
, `papers`.`paperCode`
FROM
`SOMEDBNAME`.`students`
INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`course` 
    ON (`students`.`ID` = `course`.`ID`)
INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`subject` 
    ON (`subject`.`courseID` = `course`.`courseID`)
INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`year` 
    ON (`subject`.`subjectID` = `year`.`subjectID`)
INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`papers` 
    ON (`year`.`yearID` = `papers`.`yearID`)
WHERE (`year`.`yearName` = '$dataYear'
AND `students`.`applicationNo` = '$data')");


$results = $stmt->execute(); 

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The inner join issue for PHP PDO was all over the internet. I hope this solution will help other to do there work smoothly.

I would also like to say thanks to @Kim for giving his valuable time for solving this issue.
Anyway Happy coding !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to:

```
   INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`students` 
        ON `course`.`ID` = `students`.`ID`
        INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`subject` 
        ON `subject`.`courseID` = `course`.`courseID`
        INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`year` 
        ON `year`.`subjectID` = `subject`.`subjectID`
        INNER JOIN `SOMEDBNAME`.`papers` 
        ON `papers`.`yearID` = `year`.`yearID`
   WHERE `students`.`regNo` = :regno
        AND `year`.`yearName` = :yearname";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':regno',$data,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':yearname',$dataYear,PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $results = $stmt->execute();
```

and you can simply use then:

```
$data =$_GET['appno'];
$dataYear =$_GET['year'];
```

So just to insure that problem is just your variables values, change your code for a minute to:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':regno','ABC-AA-12345',PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':yearname','Third Year',PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

and let see the result...

Comment: not returning any data - that is not fatal error, and as i asked in comments, show us all code. By the way, you can check when you return no data, try to return `$data` and `$datayear` - the problem is your values there

Comment: When i am using this query with single parameter its working but problem came when working with 2 parameter. And.And I checked the parameter value they are coming perfectly.So I think there is no issue with the parameter Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes you are wrong :-) No you are right! :-) does these words help you some way? I think the only way to resolve the problem keep trying to debug. in your case check update at the bottom of my answer for now.

Comment: Actually I am trying this from 2 days. And I am gating MAD now.Anyway I just tried the last code given by you and its seems to return some data.But I am not able to fetch it using foreach loop.kindly send me that part.

Comment: so, that example jus shows that the problem is variable values!!! for some values it brings empty results. and generally it is ok. except if you are sure that values you've sent must be valic and bring not empty result. in that case, you just need `var_dump($data);` and `var_dump($dataYear);` to see real values (if you want you can show me those dumps and we will continue together)

Comment: var_dump($data) =>>> string(13) "ABC-AA-12345" AND var_dump($dataYear) = >>> string(10) "Third Year"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71098/discussion-between-developer-and-kim-alexander).

Comment: check the chat! as soon as you asked me to continue there